# Maximum likelihood function, where did i go wrong?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

The question asks to find the MLE of theta, for the following function:
[image: question]

This was my attempt:

[image: my attempt]

And this was the solution:

[image: solution]

Where did I go wrong in my working?

Comment: Where did the $x_i$ come from? It is not there in the question or in your attempt. Also, when you write $L(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(x | \theta)$, where is the $i$ inside the product?

Comment: Likelihood based on the sample $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ should be $L(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i\mid \theta)$.

Comment: xi was in the solutions

Comment: ?? Use the $x_i$s in your solution, you will get the right answer.

Comment: but why is it the sum of log(x_i) and not just log(x_i) ?? Can you show working please

Comment: Since you do not follow the suggestion, here it is: $L(\theta)=(1+\theta)^n (\prod x_i)^{\theta}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint density is indexed by the observation number $i$, so you cannot write the step in red:  $$\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i \mid \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n (1+\theta) x_i^\theta \color{red}{\ne (1+\theta)^n x^{n\theta}}.$$  This is because $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ are not necessarily the same number; they represent a realization of your sample of observed data from this distribution.  Consequently, $$\prod_{i=1}^n (1+\theta) x_i^\theta = (1+\theta)^n \left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^\theta.$$  The log-likelihood is therefore $$\ell(\theta \mid x_1, \ldots, x_n) = n \log (1 + \theta) + \theta \log \left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i \right)= n \log (1 + \theta) + \theta \sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i.$$  In the last step, we used a generalized form of the property of logarithms $$\log ab = \log a + \log b, \quad a, b > 0.$$  The rest is straightforward.

The fact that our MLE contains a sum of logarithms of the observations should tell you that the given parametric distribution, if log-transformed, will yield a distribution for which the corresponding MLE will be a function of the (arithmetic) sample mean.  In other words, let $Y = -\log X$ (we negate the log because when $0 < X < 1$, we want $Y > 0$).  Then the density of $Y$ is $$f_Y(y) = f_X(e^{-y}) e^{-y} = (1+\theta)e^{-\theta y} e^{-y} = (1 + \theta) e^{-(1+\theta) y}, \quad y > 0.$$ This is an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda = 1+\theta$.  It is easy to compute the MLE of $\lambda$ given a log-transformed sample $$y_i = -\log x_i, \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, n:$$  the likelihood is $$\mathcal L(\lambda \mid y_1, \ldots, y_n) \propto \lambda^n e^{-\lambda \sum_{i=1}^n y_i} = \lambda^n e^{-n \lambda \bar y},$$ where $\bar y$ is the sample mean of log-transformed values.  Then the log-likelihood is $$\ell(\lambda \mid y_1, \ldots, y_n) = n \log \lambda - n \bar y \lambda$$ which attains a maximum when $$\frac{d\ell}{d\lambda} \propto \frac{1}{\lambda} - \bar y = 0,$$ or $$\hat \lambda_{\text{MLE}} = \frac{1}{\bar y}.$$  Consequently, $$\hat \theta_{\text{MLE}} = -1 + \hat \lambda_{\text{MLE}} = -1 + \frac{1}{\bar y},$$ but we established that $\bar y$, being the sample mean of (negated) log-transformed values, is $$\bar y = -\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i.$$

---

To understand what is really going on, it helps to consider a concrete numeric example.  Suppose we generate $n = 7$ observations from $X$ with $\theta = 3.14$.  I have done this for you:
$$(x_1, \ldots, x_7) = (0.86454, 0.839549, 0.890887, 0.886008, 0.867728, 0.958648, 0.8069).$$
Now, if we compute the MLE using the formula $$\hat \theta_{\text{MLE}} = -1 - \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i},$$ we first compute the negated log-transformed sample
$$(y_1, \ldots, y_7) = (0.145558, 0.17489, 0.115538, 0.121029, 0.141877, 0.0422313, 0.214556).$$
Note that these observations are exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda = \theta + 1 = 4.14$.  We take the sample mean:
$$\bar y = 0.136526.$$
Then our MLE for $\theta$ is $$\hat \theta_{\text{MLE}} = -1 + \frac{1}{\bar y} = 6.32463.$$
Of course, the MLE is not very good because $n = 7$ is a small sample.  If we do this for a large $n$, say $n = 10^5$, the performance is much improved:  in *Mathematica*, we can perform such a simulation with the input

```
-1 + 1/Mean[-Log[RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[3.14 + 1, 1], 10^5]]]
```

and the output I got was $3.14906$.

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you so much!

Comment: Why is your MLE different that that of solutions? as in the solution has 1/log... whereas you have -n/log... ??

Comment: @user11015000 The fact that two separate answers to your question arrived at the same expression for the MLE, and that they contain $n$, should suggest to you that the solution that you quoted is incorrect.  Moreover, my simulation results should also suggest that the answer must contain $n$.  If not, the estimate could be negative, which is nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

$L = (1 + \theta)^n \prod\limits_{i=1}^n x_{i}^{\theta} \Rightarrow \log L = n \log(1 + \theta) + \theta \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\log x_{i} \to \max\limits{\theta}$

$\log L^{\prime}_{\theta} = \frac{n}{1 + \theta} + \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \log x_{i} = 0 \Rightarrow \boxed{\hat{\theta} = \frac{-n}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \log x_{i}} - 1}$

Comment: How come there is no n in the solutions? But there is an n in your solution?

Comment: Solutions might be wrong some time)